# CasaOS throwing error "directory not empty" on Upload

Tags: nas, raspberry-pi

I made a home server using RPi running casaOS on top of Raspbian OS lite. Everything seems to work as it should apart of uploading files. Single files usually upload just fine. I tried to upload larger directories and they usually get some percentage uploaded but they do not finish. Instead I get this unlink error.

> unlinkat /[path]/.temp/7618642dde399612dad2e62491fae77f28/[uploaded
> folder name]: directory not empty

The problem seems to appear only when I upload to external HDD connected to the RPi. If I upload the data to the SD card I'm booting from there is no problem. I also noticed I am not able to cut the uploaded file from my SD and paste it to the HDD. It just creates a question mark file with the same name as the cut folder. The external HDD is formated as NTFS. Do you think formating it to Ext4 will solve the problem or is there something else I'm missing?